# R^2 multiple regression statsmodels OLS

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels, least-squares

I need to regress my endogenous variable `Y` on an exogenous variable `X`. `Y` looks like the following:

```
ID              0       1       2   ...        22        23        24
Date                                ...                              
1981        0.0111 -0.1685 -0.2010  ...  0.155037  0.008162 -0.038970
1982        0.2974  0.4805  0.0352  ...  0.100300  0.249513  0.165870
1983        0.1575  0.2501  0.1812  ...  0.128059  0.210568  0.444479
1984        0.0194 -0.0821 -0.1136  ...  0.200166  0.154689  0.016384
1985        0.3704  0.1424  0.2205  ...  0.279801  0.297258  0.137567
```

which means I have 25 different time-series on the columns.
My `X` looks like this:

```
           A       B       C       D       E       F       G
Date                                                        
1981 -0.1813  0.0731  0.2512 -0.0141  0.1091  0.1471 -0.0825
1982  0.1066  0.0727  0.1336 -0.0416  0.1773  0.1054  0.3473
1983  0.1374  0.1227  0.2049  0.0048  0.1606  0.0880 -0.0984
1984 -0.0605 -0.0826  0.1907  0.1523  0.0364  0.0985  0.0888
1985  0.2491 -0.0021  0.0145  0.1185 -0.0300  0.0772  0.1469
```

which means I have 7 predictors on the columns. Notice that the predictors are not characteristics of the ID of `Y`, they are rather different factors in the spirit of Factor Analysis. Now I use the following command for the regressions:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod=sm.OLS(Y,X)
res=mod.fit()
```

The model fits correctly: the `res.params` I obtain are exactly the params I get if I run a regression of each single column of `Y` on `X`, but I cannot obtain neither the R^2 nor the predicted values nor the summary. The line `print(res.summary())` gives me in fact the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (5,25) and (5,25) not aligned: 25 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

I understood this has nothing to do with the dimension of the `X`, but it is due only to the use of the `sm.OLS` for "multiple" IDs in `Y`. Of course, I could run separate regressions of each element of `Y` on `X`, save the coefficients and predicted values and calculate the R^2 on the overall observations. However, I do not understand what is the problem behind `sm.OLS`. Can somebody explain me what is happening here and a potential different workaround?

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Comment: Seems pretty specific to me. I ran into exactly the same problem doing multilabel regression with statsmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell there is no solution because two dimensional endogenous variables just aren't supported in statsmodels OLS. It's very annoying as the model appears to fit and generate coefficients just fine; it's just the methods of the fitted model expect 1D arrays for the coefficients.